# שכבת זרע and the purification of the world

Tags: tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, parashat-noach, maseches-sanhedrin

In [Sanhedrin 108b:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.108b.3?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en), it says:

> אמר רב חסדא ברותחין קלקלו בעבירה וברותחין נידונו
>
> Rav Ḥisda says: With hot semen they sinned, and with hot semen they were punished.

In Torah Ohr 8c-d, the Alter Rebbe says (quoted from Chabad.org [here](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/246609/jewish/The-Story-of-Noah-and-the-Ark-in-the-Bible.htmhttps://)):

> Chassidic teachings describe the Flood as a cleansing process. The waters of the Flood are like the waters of a ritual bath—a mikvah—where the waters spiritually cleanse the one who enters it. The world similarly received a spiritual cleansing, setting the course of history on a course of hope and purpose. And just as a mikvah must contain 40 seah (an ancient measure of volume), so did the rains of the Flood last for forty days.

In [Positive Commandment 105](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/900287/jewish/Positive-Commandment-105.htm) in the Rambam's Sefer Hamitzvos (summarizing the mitzvah found in [Vayikra Chapter 15](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9916/jewish/Chapter-15.htm)), it is written:

> We are commanded regarding the ritual impurity [contained in and emitted by] semen. [I.e., when contracted, one must follow all the laws associated with this impurity.]

Then the question arises: how can these "waters" (possibly שכבת זרע) of the flood be used as a mechanism to purify the world? שכבת זרע is *inherently* tamei!

Comment: I dont agree to your translation, With hot semen they sinned, and with hot semen they were punished. They were punished with 'hot' water.

Comment: The whole question is based on a wrong translation/assumption. You might want to ask a Rabbi before asking questions on translations. VTC.

Comment: Please remember it well that on Sefaria you see with bold the literal translation and with normal typeface the interpretation. The [רת"ח root](https://www.pealim.com/dict/?num-radicals=3&r1=%D7%A8&r2=%D7%AA&rf=%D7%97) is only connected to _boiling._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The translation is: "With hot semen they sinned, and with hot **water** they were punished". This translation can also be found in the very source you quote  [Sanhedrin 108b:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.108b.3?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en). A similar translation can be found [here](http://www.halakhah.com/sanhedrin/sanhedrin_108.html) as well.

Comment: Actually OP's translation was also taken from Sefaria. The translation was just updated today, after I sent them a comment based on this question.

Comment: It's probably obvious but what does OP stand for

Comment: @Yaakov "Original Poster" which in this case refers to the person who wrote the question

Comment: Thanks :)
I didn't realize that, the question makes more sense now.
In general I have found many mistranslations with the Sefaria Talmud

Comment: @simyou Skayach! But is it so in Steinsaltz?